# How to divide rows to two table with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ui-tree

how to divide rows to two tables with angularjs

```
<tr ng-repeat="field in node.fields track by $index" ui-tree-node="" class="ng-scope angular-ui-tree-node" collapsed="false" ng-if="$even">
```

I have tried this but it is not working for drag and drop

Comment: larger description will help more :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="element in awesomeThings">
<div ng-if="$even">
    <td class="even">
        <a href="#">
            {{element}}
        </a>
    </td>
</div>
<div ng-if="$odd">
    <td class="odd">
        <a href="#">
            {{element}}
        </a>
    </td>
</div>
</tr>
```